# Discriminating between two different structs, nested in a union, with common attributes in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, unions, discriminator

Given this quickly done example in which I want to be able to search the `animals` array by the common attributes (either `color` or `mainFoodSource`) and output only the `bears`, or `snake`s with the matching attribute specified.

Given my array of `animals` being defined like so:

```
struct animal{
    char key; //I believe this is a correct usage of a discriminator

    union myUnion{
          char mainFoodSource[10];
          int numLimbs : 3;

           struct bear{     
                char blackOrBrown[5];
                float height;      //in feet standing
           } b;

           struct snake{                 
                float length;
                char mainColor[20];
           } s;            
    } u;
} animals[20];
```

How would I be able to discriminate each element in the array of being either a `bear`, or a `snake`, using that `char key`;I have put before the union?

Comment: Why are mainFoodSource and numLimbs members of the union?

Comment: You need to acquaint yourself bit more with the concept of classes (base and derived), inheritance, etc. You probably need to derive classes for the different animals and then store them in base-class-type array or something similar

Comment: There are no "classes" while programming in C. For this question i have made my information for storing the information in a header file and must have an interactive option to print only certain features based on a search. Everything works perfectly... Except I cannot decipher between two different structs in the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a suggestion based on what you have explained in the requirement.

Have the variable key to store 'b' for denoting its a bear and 's' if its a snake.

The myUnion will allocate a maximum memory of (sizeof(float)+sizeof(char[20]);

Try to have the mainColor and mainFoodSource within a single struct variable to prevent confusion.